# PHP7 serial communication - dio package

Tags: php, serial-port, php-7

According to [this](https://github.com/gophp7/gophp7-ext/wiki/extensions-catalog) it seems that php 7 doesn't support dio package. Is there a way to connect to serial port in php 7, without dio package?

Comment: Indeed that extension has been unbundled and mored to a separate PECL package long ago. Apparently that package has not received any updates in a long while. You may want to give it a try to build it yourself though.

Comment: @arkascha I did that, but it fails compiling because of too many arguments for ```zend_hash_find ```

Comment: Ok, so you would have to port the package to php-7, since Zend has apparently changed the API then. That is indeed more effort. You have to ask yourself if it is worth it.

Comment: There appear to be available many alternatives for unixoid systems (so Linux), since those systems allow device access in a uniform manner via file based functions. That is not possible for other operating systems, namely not for MS-Windows.

Comment: There are some projects on GitHub, but they all appear heavily outdated by now.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks, but how can I port package to php-7. I'm on a unixoid system :))

Comment: Well, you have a clear error message and the Zend API is documented. You should be able to dive into the code and adapt the existing implementation so that it again works with the newer API. Afterwards you _should_ be able to build the package. I have not taken a look into the code, so I can not say anything about the effort required. But in my experience it is well worth taking a closer look. And, by the way, this is a great opportunity to contribute something to the ecosystem. Maybe you want to setup a forked repository on GitHub and revive that extension!

Comment: @arkascha Thanks, It seems really interesting. Specially the community contribution part ;)

Comment: Sure, go for it! This is what makes OpenSource projects great! If you take a closer look into it take care to contact the original authors or maintainers. You will certainly find their identity and addresses in the code. They will be able to help and give you important hints. Don't hesitate to do that. And, also, don't hesitate to publish your result, even if unfinished. Working together is more efficient!

Comment: @arkascha Awesome help thank you, very much!

Comment: You are welcome :-) Report back, if you have questions or a result!

Comment: Sure, I'll @arkascha

Comment: There is already work on this [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72270).